# Compiler not calling appropriate generic overload when passed with value type

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, overloading, value-type

I have public functions like this:

```
public static T Get<T>(this Mango m, T defaultValue = default(T)) where T : class
{
    //do something; return something;
}

public static T? Get<T>(this Mango m, T? defaultValue = default(T?)) where T : struct
{
    //do something; return something;
}
```

Basically I want to individually handle reference types and nullable types. It compiles; until i call for value types. For reference types it compiles.

```
mango.Get<string>(); // compiles..
mango.Get(""); // compiles..

mango.Get<int>(); // The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as 
                  // parameter 'T' in the generic type or method Get<T>(Mango, T)
//also            // The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
                  // Get<int>(Mango, int) and Get<int>(Mango, int?)
```

**What real ambiguity is here? When `T` is `int`, cant it call the struct overload appropriately?** Also:

```
mango.Get<int>(0);  // The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as 
                    // parameter 'T' in the generic type or method Get<T>(Mango, T)
```

**Why is the compiler only detecting the reference type overload?** I tried having two separate overloads:

```
public static T Get<T>(this Mango m) where T : class
{
    return default(T);
}

public static T? Get<T>(this Mango m) where T : struct
{
    return default(T);
}

public static T Get<T>(this Mango m, T def) where T : class
{
    return default(T);
}

public static T? Get<T>(this Mango m, T? def) where T : struct
{
    return default(T);
}
```

The problem persisted. **And obviously, the first two methods dont compile here since overloading doesn't work merely on the basis of constraints.**

I tried by removing the `class` constrained overload and keeping just the `struct` constrained one, like this:

```
public static T? Get<T>(this Mango m, T? defaultValue = default(T?)) where T : struct
{
    //do something; return something;
}

mango.Get<int>(); // voila compiles!
mango.Get<int>(0); // no problem at all..
// but now I can't have mango.Get<string>() for instance :(
```

**Am I only left with renaming the two functions?** I feel its appropriate to have a unified name so that the caller just doesnt have to worry about the implementation detail, but just call `Get` for any type.

**Update:** Marc's solution doesnt work if I have to avoid the optional parameter.

```
mango.Get<int>(); // still wouldnt work!!
```

**But there's more magic :(:(**

```
public static bool IsIt<T>(this T? obj) where T : struct
{
    return who knows;
}

public static bool IsIt<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    return perhaps;
}
```

By all means I'm expecting the same compiler bug (according to me) to annoy me. But no it works this time.

```
Guid? g = null;
g.IsIt(); //just fine, and calls the struct constrained overload
"abcd".IsIt(); //just fine, and calls the class constrained overload
```

**So if overload resolution comes before constraint checking as Marc says, shouldn't I get the same error this time too? But no. Why is it so??** What the hell is going on? :x

Comment: Halfway through your post I was going to suggest to only try the struct version, but you already did that and it compiles. _Seems_ to me this is a genuine bug and should be reported.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: No bug, see Marcs answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth cant be a bug, but surely if it was supported this could have been a handy feature!

Comment: I would also just rename.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks, learn something new every day!

Comment: And when I tried to introduce this overload: `public static V? Get<V>(this Mango m, V defaultValue) where V : struct` where the last parameter `defaultValue` is a value-type that is _not_ nullable, then it won't compile because my new overload is considered to have the same signature as the first one (the one with `class` constraint).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thats fine, cos overload is irrespective of constraint. it depends only method name and argument signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

constraint checking is done **after** overload resolution, IIRC; the overload resolution seems to prefer the first version. You can force it to use the other, though:

```
mango.Get<int>((int?)0);
```

or even:

```
mango.Get((int?)0);
```

Personally, I'd probably just change the name to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: will get back to u after some testing.

Comment: @MarcGravell Anyway, maybe the thing is... why you would need an overload for the non-null? A non-null can be implicitly casted to nullable. Or maybe using optional params instead of overloading? If the nullable int isn't null, do some stuff, if not, do other stuff and use the non-nullable int.

Comment: It is interesting why it prefers the first overload on `mango.Get(0)`, though. Now make the methods non-generic and the argument compulsory, so write these overloads: `static void M(int? i) { }` and `static void M(object o) { }`, then the call `M(0)` could either box the `int` and call the `object` overload or wrap the `int` to a nullable type and call that overload. But since every `Nullable<int>` is an `Object`, and the converse is not true, the _nullable_ overload is most "specialized" and must be preferred. So `M(0)` goes to `M((int?)0)`, not `M((object)0)`. So what about `mango.Get(0)`?

Comment: Marc, sadly your solution doesnt work for `mango.Get<int>()`. Can u find my update on the question?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the compiler will check the constraints specified within generic types that are used within a method signature, but not for constraints within the signature itself.

Thus, if a method accepted two parameters, one of type `T where T : struct` along with a `Nullable<T>[]`, the compiler would not consider the method for any `T` that was not a struct.  The method's specified `struct` constraint for `T` is not considered in evaluating overloads, but the fact that `Nullable<T>` constrains `T` to struct, is.

I really find the total inability to consider constraints in overload evaluation bizarre, given that one could specify a default null value for the `Nullable<T>[]` parameter, and pretend the parameter didn't exist.  The vb.net compilers and C# compilers seem to differ, though, when it comes to what they regard as ambiguous and what they accept.

Comment: `the compiler will check the constraints specified within generic types that are used within a method signature, but not for constraints within the signature itself.` was very confusing, but `The method's specified struct constraint for T is not considered in evaluating overloads, but the fact that Nullable<T> constrains T to struct, is.` helped :) Does vb infer overload correctly in my case?

Comment: @nawfal: It does not, but adding a dummy parameter of a type which includes a class-constrained constained generic type parameter (in the same way that `Nullable<T>` includes a struct-constrained generic type parameter) can help; vb.net still perceives ambiguity in the case of two signatures that are identical except for a default-null dummy parameter, but if you don't need the generic type parameter within the function, you might be able to have it take a parameter of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer myself.

As marc says, **constraint checking is done after overload resolution**, and between

```
public static T Get<T>(this Mango m, T defaultValue = default(T)) where T : class
{
    //do something; return something;
}
```

and

```
public static T? Get<T>(this Mango m, T? defaultValue = default(T?)) where T : struct
{
    //do something; return something;
}
```

overload resolution prefers the `class` version. But that's only when the compiler is given a choice between two similar overloads (**without the optional parameter in which case both the overloads becomes the same, neglecting constraint**). Now when the constraint is applied, the call fails for `Get<int>` since `int` is not `class`.

Things change a bit when default parameter is provided. If I call

```
mango.Get(0);
```

The compiler is able enough to call the right overload, but which overload now accepts `int` or `T where T: struct`? There is not one. In the given example, the second parameter is expected to be `T?` and not `T`. **The compiler doesnt automatically resolve overloading by applying all the available casts for every argument type. It isn't a bug, but thats one less a feature, thats all**. If I do this:

```
int? i = 0;
mango.Get(i);
```

it works, the right overload is called. This is what is happening in the second example too. It works because I'm providing the right parameter.

When I call:

```
Guid? g = null;
g.IsIt();
```

`obj` is known to be `g` and hence `T` equals `Guid`. But if I call

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
g.IsIt();
```

This doesn't work, since `g` is now `Guid` and not `Guid?` and compiler doesnt do the casting automatically, instead one have to tell the compiler explicitly.

**I'm ok with the fact that the compiler doesn't do the casting automatically since that will be too much to calculate for every possible type, but what appears to be a deficiency in C# is the fact that constraint checking is not involved in overload resolution.** That is even if I provide the type like `mango.Get<int>()` or `mango.Get<int>(0)` the overload resolution won't prefer the `struct` version and use `default(int?)` for argument `defaultValue`. Looks odd to me.